# DBT - 1046 (3D000): No database selected

Tags: dbt

Hi I just created a dbt project using

`dbt init puddle`

I have a MySQL database running locally and have defined my profiles.yml as follows

```
puddle:
  target: dev
  outputs:
    dev:
      type: mysql5
      server: localhost
      port: 3306  # optional
      database: puddle
      dbname: puddle
      schema: puddle
      username: test
      password: test
      driver: MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver
    prod:
      type: mysql5
      server: [server/host]
      port: [port]  # optional
      database: [schema] # optional, should be same as schema
      schema: [schema]
      username: [username]
      password: [password]
      driver: MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver
```

But when I run `dbt run` I get the following error

```
02:48:52  1 of 2 START table model puddle.my_first_dbt_model.............................. [RUN]
02:48:52  1 of 2 ERROR creating table model puddle.my_first_dbt_model..................... [ERROR in 0.11s]
02:48:52  2 of 2 SKIP relation puddle.my_second_dbt_model................................. [SKIP]
02:48:52  
02:48:52  Finished running 1 table model, 1 view model in 0.31s.
02:48:52  
02:48:52  Completed with 1 error and 0 warnings:
02:48:52  
02:48:52  Database Error in model my_first_dbt_model (models/example/my_first_dbt_model.sql)
02:48:52    1046 (3D000): No database selected
02:48:52    compiled SQL at target/run/puddle/models/example/my_first_dbt_model.sql
```

How am I suppose to select the database??

Comment: Can you share how your `my_first_dbt_model ` model looks like?

Comment: I've tried adding database/target_database to dbt_project.yml and schema.yml, and in the config of the model
Here is a link to a screenshot of my setup
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/30641101/194828701-e917bf70-4cca-44b5-bb76-2159ae6b9399.png

Comment: Why aren't you using `select * from {{ source('source_name', 'table_name') }}` ? Have you declared your sources?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same problem. This seems to be an issue in the `dbt-mysql` package. Took me a while to get my head around it, but the answer is somewhat hidden in the [dbt docs](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/model-configs#configuring-directories-of-models-in-dbt_projectyml) itself.

You need to configure a `pre-hook` for your models in your `dbt_project.yml`. A little bit counter-intuitive, but you must have your project name as your first level in the models section again, even though it won't appear in your folder structure. This way, I got it to work properly with dbt 1.4.9 (latest version supported from dbt-mysql).

Please find a sample `dbt_project.yml` attached.

```yaml
# Name your project! Project names should contain only lowercase characters
# and underscores. A good package name should reflect your organization's
# name or the intended use of these models
name: 'puddle'
version: '1.0.0'
config-version: 2

# This setting configures which "profile" dbt uses for this project.
profile: 'puddle'

# These configurations specify where dbt should look for different types of files.
# The `model-paths` config, for example, states that models in this project can be
# found in the "models/" directory. You probably won't need to change these!
model-paths: ["models"]


# Configuring models
# Full documentation: https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/configuring-models

# In this example config, we tell dbt to build all models in the example/
# directory as views. These settings can be overridden in the individual model
# files using the `{{ config(...) }}` macro.
models:
  puddle: # important, you need the project name as first level again, even though it's not in the folder structure
    <your-models-namespace>:
      +pre-hook:
        - "USE {{ target.schema }}"
```